# Does pandas loc generates a copy in itself but it is a view with assignment?

Tags: python, pandas

## Question

Does `.loc` generate both view and copy depending on the context?

### Background

A bit confused with pandas `.loc` behaviour as I had thought it should generate a view. However, it looks it generates a copy in the example below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_for_view = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(10, (3, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
back_for_view = df_for_view
print(back_for_view)
---
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  5  3  7  3
1  3  3  8  3  2
2  1  7  6  8  4
```

Use `.loc` which generates a copy.

```
df_for_view = df_for_view.loc[:, ['B']]
print(df_for_view.values.base is back_for_view.values.base)
---
False   # <--- .loc has generated a copy because the base is different
```

Update the `.loc` generated does not reflect.

```
df_for_view.loc[:, :] = -1
print(back_for_view)
---
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  5  3  7  3
1  3  3  8  3  2
2  1  7  6  8  4
```

On the other hand, if the update assignment occurs in the same line, it looks `.loc` generates a view.

```
df_for_view = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(10, (3, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
back_for_view = df_for_view

print(f"df_for_view is \n{df_for_view}\n")
print("updating...")
df_for_view.loc[:, ['B']] = -1

print(f"df_for_view is \n{df_for_view}\n")
print(f"back_for_view is \n{back_for_view}\n")

print(df_for_view.values.base is back_for_view.values.base)
print(df_for_view.loc[:, ['B']].values.base is back_for_view.values.base)
```

Result:

```
df_for_view is 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  7  7  0  5  1
1  7  3  7  3  6
2  3  0  5  4  8

updating...
df_for_view is 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  7 -1  0  5  1
1  7 -1  7  3  6
2  3 -1  5  4  8

back_for_view is 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  7 -1  0  5  1
1  7 -1  7  3  6
2  3 -1  5  4  8

True
False
```

So, `.loc` generates a view or copy depends on the context in which it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, it seems that is more about assignment vs copy.
`df_for_view.loc[:, ['B']]` is essentially a new dataframe, as it's proved by

```
print(df_for_view.loc[:, ['B']].values.base is back_for_view.values.base)

False
```

so `df_for_view = df_for_view.loc[:, ['B']]`

could have been any other df like

```
df_for_view = df_any
```

which is a dataframe copy.

Now, this is assigning -1, an integer, to every element in the df:

```
df_for_view.loc[:, :] = -1
```

it could have been

```
df_for_view.at[:, :] = -1
```

and have the same effect, or even something like:

```
df_for_view.loc[:,:] = df_for_view.loc[2:2]
```

In summary, I think the difference is that in the first case loc is generating a new dataframe to be copied over another, and in the second case is used to reference every element in a dataframe.